# Retrieve LDAP security groups created in the past 15 minuites

Tags: active-directory, ldap, ldap-query

I would like to retrieve Windows Security Groups created in the past 15 mins from Active Directory.

I have tried to find if anyone has created such an LDAP query in the past but have had no luck.

any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A LDAP Filter something like:

```
(&(groupType:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2147483648)(whenCreated>=20180301000000.0Z))
```

Should do the work.
groupType:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2147483648 will return all [All Security Groups (local, global and universal)](http://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Active%20Directory%20Group%20Related%20Searches) and whenCreated>=20180301000000.0Z implies all created after the provided time.